# I need to have all values with the same key in one line

Tags: c++

need your help. I have the following problem , for example i have a formula how i can check if a station is on each line. I found it , but then i need to check everytime and it can be that one line has 10 stations. Then i take a line ( multimap) create a name of a line and also stations which are on that line. The following code i have so far implemented.

```
multimap<int, int>numberofStation;
for (int newSt = 0; newSt <dimentionOfNewStation; newSt++)
{
    int station = 0;

    for (int Edges = 0; Edges < dimenstionOfEdges; Edges++)
        {
        float firstsol = 0;
        float secondsol = 0;
        float thirdsol = 0;
        firstsol = (busEdges[Edges].y2 - busEdges[Edges].y1) / (busEdges[Edges].x2 - busEdges[Edges].x1);//check if a station on that line
        secondsol = (apointCollection4[newSt].y- busEdges[Edges].y1) / (apointCollection4[newSt].x - busEdges[Edges].x1);//check if a station on that line
        thirdsol = (busEdges[Edges].y2 - apointCollection4[newSt].y) / (busEdges[Edges].x2 - apointCollection4[newSt].x);//check if a station on that line

            if (firstsol == secondsol && firstsol == thirdsol)//values should be the same
                {
                    station = Edges;//i take that edge/line(id)
                }


        }
    if (numberofStation.find(station) == numberofStation.end())
    {
        numberofStation.insert(pair<int, int>(station, newSt));//i add that station to that line
    }
    else
    {
        here i need to have a line of station for each line( 0 line has 2,5,3 station)
    }

}
for (auto it = numberofStation.begin(); it != numberofStation.end(); it++)
{
    and how i can print it out in the order i want above.

}
```

Tell me please if it is possible to imlement such idea or maybe it is quite crazy and tell me please the way how i can do that.
So the idea , i need to find the number of stations on each line.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: As i commented in the code. I want to achieve having the followin : Each line should have the stations (not the amount of stations because i can do it without problems ) but exactly which station lies on which line and if a line has 2 and more stations , it should display line (0) has 1 , 2 , 3 ,4 (id of stations)

Comment: what "lines" / "stations" are you talking about? I find this quite confusing

Comment: newSt ( for example i go to the first loop take the first station) then go to the second loop take the first edge ( line with coordinates) . I check on which edge that newSt lies and if it lies on the second edge ( i need edge(2) has 0 newSt. Then i go to the first loop again , take the second newSt check , if it lies also on the edge (2) , i need to have edge(2) has 0 , 1 ..... Line is edge ( i just called it edge because in my code each edge has x , y and x1,y1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like [selyunin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36446896/i-need-to-have-all-values-with-the-same-key-in-one-line#comment-60506824) I'm not quite sure what you're asking for.
*Maybe* it's [std::equal_range()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range) or (since it's a multimap anyway) [std::multimap::equal_range](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/equal_range/) like in

```
std::multimap<int,int> m;
m.insert(pair<int, int>(0, 1));
m.insert(pair<int, int>(2, 2));
m.insert(pair<int, int>(1, 3));
m.insert(pair<int, int>(1, 4));
m.insert(pair<int, int>(0, 5));
m.insert(pair<int, int>(1, 6));

int station = 1;

// get the range of entries having (station) as "key"/first   
auto r = m.equal_range(station);
while(r.first!=r.second) {
    cout << (*(r.first)).second << ' ';
    r.first++;
}
```

which prints `3 4 6`

Comment: try it in couple minutes and then if it works , tell you